# Uniform convergence of $\left(f_n:\ [0,1)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}:\ x \mapsto x^n\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}x\right)\right)_n$

Tags: real-analysis

To prove the uniform convergence of $\left(f_n:\ [0,1)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}:\ x \mapsto x^n\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}x\right)\right)_n$ ,to the zero function, the best I could think of is the theorem of Dini but can this be proven directly from the definition of uniform convergence?

What I'd need is decreasing upper bound of $x^n\cos(\frac{\pi}{2})$ for every $x\in[0,1)$ but I can't think of any.

[image]

Comment: You cannot use Dini here because your space is not compact.

Comment: Extending the domain, $f$ is continuous on $[0,1]$; thus, uniformly continuous on $[0,1]$, hence on $[0,1)$. But, did you mean to ask about uniform convergence of a sequence?

Comment: Alex, thankyou, I hadn't even noticed that.

Comment: David, yes, let me edit the question.

Comment: Given $\epsilon>0$, choose $1>\delta>0$ such that $\cos{\pi x\over2}<\epsilon$ for all $x\in(\delta,1)$. Then choose $N$ such that $x^n<\epsilon$ for all $n>N$ and all $x\in[0,\delta]$. This $N$ "works". (There's no need to find things explicitly.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard approach does work, although not as concretely as perhaps you're used to. Find the critical point(s) of $f_n$. Here, other than $x=0$, you get the point $x_n$ satisfying $\cot(\frac{\pi}2 x_n) = \frac{\pi}{2n}x_n$. Since the right-hand side goes to $0$ (remember that $x_n\in [0,1]$), it follows that $\cos(\frac{\pi}2 x_n)\to 0$, and therefore $0\le f_n(x_n) \le \cos(\frac{\pi}2 x_n) \to 0$.

Comment: Do you mean $\cos$ instead of $\cot$?

Comment: Nope. When you do the product rule, you'll end up with both $\cos$ and $\sin$.

Comment: Wait a minute, I don't get why you would get derivatives into this...

Comment: Because to find the maximum value of $f_n$, we want to (check endpoints and) find critical points of $f_n$. I was assuming you were used to these sorts of problems, sorry. :)

Comment: Ah wow, you skipped over too many steps at once for me there. Now it's clear, thank you!

Comment: It's always hard to know what people know and what they don't. You're welcome.

Comment: Pretty slick.${}$